# Using jsonP in vanillaJS, works well except in IE

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, jsonp

I have some troubles with my script, I'm using a jsonP request creating a script tag pointing to my 2nd domain, like here:

```
recupDataScript = function() {
    var otherDomain = "http://www.otherdomain.com/check?q=recupData",
    script = document.createElement('script'),
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = otherDomain;
    document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

And after I get my data with this simple function:

```
window.recupData = function(data){
    alert(data);
}
```

There is a PHP script on the page of my second domain that send a jsonP answer.

In all browsers I get the answer Object Object, and in IE(7, 8 or 9), I get undefined answer, except if I check the auto management of cookies in the setting in IE, but it isn't set by default.

I have tested with the jQuery script:

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://www.otherdomain.com/check?q=?",
   function(data) {
      alert(data);
   });
```

and I get the same problem (working everywhere except on IE)

But when I use my script I can't get the flickr I got the same good answer on IE and other. But I can't get the good answer using my own script, maybe I can solve this problem exploring the way to get the jsonP of flickr without jQuery.